# Min value of few values in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, min

Is there any way to find minimum value of 3 column values in ssrs ?

I need to set the found mininmum value in next column's expression.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DataSet has three fields `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, you can use an expression similar to this:

```
=Switch(Fields!val2.Value >= Fields!val1.Value and Fields!val3.Value >= Fields!val1.Value,
        Fields!val1.Value, 
        Fields!val1.Value >= Fields!val2.Value and Fields!val3.Value >= Fields!val2.Value,
        Fields!val2.Value, 
        Fields!val1.Value >= Fields!val3.Value and Fields!val2.Value >= Fields!val3.Value,
        Fields!val3.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks... but i am searching for n number of columns... just for example i said 3 columns..